# Remove duplicates from DataGridView but keep the count?

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview with data I pull from an SQL Server. It comes back with some data that are duplicates. I want to remove all the duplicates but keep count of how many there are of each unique items. Here is an example of what the data looks like...

[image: sample]

```
For intI = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    For intJ = intI - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(intI).Cells(1).Value = 
DataGridView1.Rows(intJ).Cells(1).Value AndAlso 
DataGridView1.Rows(intI).Cells(3).Value = 
DataGridView1.Rows(intJ).Cells(3).Value Then
    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(intI)
     Exit For
  End If
Next
Next
```

So I can remove all the duplicates, but I want to be able to have a count of all the items in the end, including the duplicates. For example, There are 5 CA, I want to remove 4 leaving just 1 unique one, but I want to show that there are 5 CA in my datagridview next to California.

So in the end, I want the datagridview to have something like :

State | Short

California | 5

Here is my Query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SELECT
    States , Shorts 
FROM
    DAT.States
        INNER JOIN
    DATR.[Shorts]
WHERE @StartDate IS NULL
```

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

I came up with a method of counting the GridView1 into GridView2 but I'm not exactly sure on the code. Maybe I could get some help with this part instead?

```
For i As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 To 1 Step -1
    For j As Integer = DataGridView2.RowCount - 1 To 1 Step -1
        'If Grid2.Row(j).Cells(1).Value = Grid1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value Then
        '   Grid2 already has that value, +1 to Column 2 of Cell(j)
        '   Delete row(i)
        'Else
        'Value does not exist, add row(i) into Grid2, and in the 2nd column of Grid2, the count is 1
        'End If
    Next
Next
```

The end result for GridView2 would be something like :

[image: sample]

Here is my code I came up with to try and count the States in Column 1 and then delete it and add it to the Grid2, but it's not working...

```
Dim Counts As Integer = 0
Dim State As String = ""
Dim CurLoop As Integer = 0

        Do Until CurLoop > DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            State = DataGridView1.Rows(CurLoop).Cells(0).Value
            For i As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 To 1 Step -1
                If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = State Then
                    Counts += 1
                    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
                End If
            Next
            DataGridView2.Rows.Add(State, Counts)
            State = ""
            Counts = 0
            CurLoop += 1
        Loop
```

Comment: Is this VBA or VB.Net? The two are not the same.

Comment: Show your query.

Comment: This is VB.NET, but I am also working with Access so it is also VB.NET. I can just translate the VB.NET over to VBA however once I have a working solution

Comment: _This is VB.NET, but I am also working with Access so it is also VB.NET_ ??

Comment: I'm sorry I meant to say VBA, it's a bit cold here so my fingers are moving on their own haha

Comment: Here is my query : https://pastebin.com/XA23DrbC

Comment: Oh, I will edit it into my post, I don't know why I didn't think of that...

Comment: I was thinking I can do something like, create a 2nd DataGridView, and run through each row of the first column. Take the text of the cell and move it over to the 2nd GridView. If the value from GridView1 already exist in GridView2, +1 to the 2nd column in GridView2 where the text is. If it doesn't exist, add it and continue.

I'm not sure how the code for that would look like though. I know I'll have to use a For Each loop for both the GridViews

Comment: *I meant to say VBA* If it is a DataGridView, I can assure you is not VBA

Comment: I have removed the vba tag.

Comment: If you are using Sql Server where does Access come into the picture? Your query is very confusing to me. @EndDate is not used in the query. Are State and Shorts in the same table? What two fields are the 2 tables joined on? Do you want to remove the rows just in the grid or delete the record in the database also? Select Count(State) ...Group By State and Select Distinct come to mind but I am really not sure what is happening here.

Comment: I just want to remove the rows from the Grid, leave only 1 unique State, and in the 2nd column have the count of how many there are in total. The Access part comes after I figure out the solution to this problem, so I guess I shouldn't have mention it.

Comment: That query looks bonkers wrong in so many ways.  Does that really return the information we see in the grid?

Comment: I have edited the OP with a bit more information

Comment: What do you mean @preciousbetine? Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: So according to your comment, you can't work with the source data; you just receive the results and have to handle that info. What do you receive: a DataTable, an array, the dataReader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer to my own question. It's not the prettiest solution but it works. If anyone else is in need of something like this, here is what I did...

```
Dim Counts As Integer = 0
Dim State As String = ""
Dim CurLoop As Integer = 0

        Do Until CurLoop > DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            State = DataGridView1.Rows(CurLoop).Cells(0).Value
            For i As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 To 1 Step -1
                If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = State Then
                    Counts += 1
                    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
                End If
            Next
            DataGridView2.Rows.Add(State, Counts)
            State = ""
            Counts = 0
            CurLoop += 1
        Loop

        Counts = DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value
        Counts += 1
        DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = Counts
```

For some reason, whatever in the first row of Grid1 is, it's always 1 lower than what it's supposed to be, so I add 1 to it in the end.